# Why subsequent form submit is not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I'm doing AJAX form validation. The logic here is that first all fields are sent to the server and if it responds 'ok', then the form submit is proceeding via the `submit()` function.

The success of the validation is stored in the `validate` hidden input. Everything is fine, the script asks the server, then prints `validated` by `console.log` but form won't submit. I've Googled a `e.returnValue = true;` trick but it has not helped.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form.validate').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $submit = $form.find('input[type=submit]');
    var $validate = $form.find('input[name=_validate]');
    if ($validate.length > 0 && $validate.val() == 'success') { // already validated
      e.returnValue = true;
      console.log('validated');
      return true; // submit form
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($validate.length == 0)
      $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="_validate" value="asking" />');

    $validate = $form.find('input[name=_validate]');
    var params = $form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      method: 'post',
      data: params
    }).then(function(response, statusText, xhrObj) {
      var json = JSON.parse(response);
      if (json._status != 'ok') {
        // print errors
      } else {
        $validate.val('success');
        $form.submit();
      }
    }).catch(function(data) {
      alert('Error occured');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: try `$form[0].submit();`

Comment: TypeError: $form[0].submit is not a function

Comment: so that means you have a button named submit, change the name/id of it

Comment: Thanks, it worked out... But I can't get how could it block the function?

Comment: "But I can't get how could it block the function?" not sure what you are asking